# Creating new associations after multiple checkboxes ticked

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a 'service' model which is constant and has an 'id' column and a 'service_type' column.

'service' belong_to_and_has_many 'profiles'

When creating their profile a user can choose which services they provide via multiple choice check boxes.

On submission I want to add the services to the users profile.

Currently I'm tying to do this by using the values of the array of 'services' from the service params and trying to loop over the array in the controller adding association for each elements value in the array, suffice to say its a bit of a mess and not working and I need help trying to make it work.

Controller:

```
def create
@profile = Profile.new(profile_params)

if @profile.save 
    add = []
    types = params(:services)
    types.each do |service|
    p = Service.where('service_type LIKE ?', '%#{service}%')
    add << p
   self.services << add
  end 

  redirect_to '/' 

else
  render '/profiles'
end
end

def profile_params
params.require(:profile).permit(:bio, :services, london_attributes: [:id, :south, :north, :east, :west, :central])
```

end

View: - each ="name" is the same as a 'service_type' in the 'service' model:

```
<h3>Please click the services you provide</h3>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <label> <input type="checkbox" name="profile[services][]" value="handyman">Handyman</label>
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox">
        <label> <input type="checkbox" name="profile[services][]" value="plumber">Plumber</label>
      </div>
```

Params with token an other params removed:

```
Parameters: "profile"=>{
  "bio"=>"",
  "services"=>
    ["handyman", "plumber"]}}
Unpermitted parameter: services
```

profile.rb:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :places
  has_and_belongs_to_many :services
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :places
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :services
  has_one :london
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :london
```

Comment: How does your `profile_params` look like?

Comment: And what does the view look like?

Comment: @pavan have added the profile_params above.

Comment: @jvillian do you need the whole view?

Comment: No, just the bit where you're generating the check boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unpermitted parameter: services

You should change `:services` to `:service_ids => []` in `profile_params`

```
def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:bio, :service_ids => [], london_attributes: [:id, :south, :north, :east, :west, :central])
end
```

And use [**collection_check_boxes**](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes) to generate the check boxes.

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:service_ids, Service.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Also change the `create` method to below

```
def create
@profile = Profile.new(profile_params)

if @profile.save 
  redirect_to '/' 
else
  render '/profiles'
end
end
```

Comment: Champion!  One question though how can you get away with passing only 4 arguments to collection_check_boxes but it expects 5 .. 7?